# Azure VM: Cannot add a Reserved IP address to an existing old VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm attempting to reserve the (V)IP address of an existing Azure service, using the following command:

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -Location "North Europe" -ServiceName "my-existing-service"
```

The command fails with the error:

```
New-AzureReservedIP : BadRequest : Cannot reserve the ip of deployment myserver.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -Location " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureReservedIP], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzureReservedIPCmdlet
```

The VM is over a year old, and after a bit of reading online, believe this error is because the cloud service API may be out of date. The only suggested way I've found to add a reserved IP is to completely deallocate the VM's and cloud service, but then we'll get allocated a new IP address.

We can't really afford to lose the current IP address as it is set up for IP-based security with third parties and will involve a whole load of paperwork, firewall changes and time.

Does anyone know of a way to convert an existing old VIP to a reserved IP, without deallocating the VM's and losing the current IP address?

**Updated:** We mainly want this to allow stopping/starting servers to prevent being charged outside of office hours, while retaining the IP, but also to protect against an accidental stop/deallocation. So can't use the "stayprovisioned" flag on Stop-AzureVM to achieve this, as billing will continue.

Comment: You can add an IP to existing vm. N.B. - Dont stop the server before perfomoing the operation using portal. Use PS command stop-azurevm -servicename "svcname" -name "vmname" -stayprovisioned. So, that is older IP is preserved even if VM is stopped or rebooted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902528/how-to-add-additional-ip-to-an-azure-vm-which-is-running/32499251#32499251

Comment: Subject to condition your VM size allows you to add additional IPs. The above link will surely help you.

Comment: Thanks but we need a reserved, public IP.  We want the reservation to exist even when the servers are de-allocated/de-provisioned.  The reason is that we want billing to stop on the servers out of office hours.  Using the stayprovisioned flag will carry on billing. I will update the question.

Comment: Please update your question

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer to this, and it's pretty simple.  When you do an update to a VM it appears it also updates the API for the VM.

After running:

```
Get-AzureVM servername | Update-AzureVM
```

I was able to run New-AzureReservedIP
 works without error.